# Is possible execute an operation just after an Activity is closed in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

Basically, I open an another activity "Activity2" from "Activity1".
I would like executing "function1" (in Activity1) just after Activity2 is closed.
Is it possibile? And How?

```
Intent(this, Activity2::class.java).also {
    startActivity(it)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `startActivityForResult` and it will give you the result in `onActivityResult`.

**Activity1**

```
Intent(this, Activity2::class.java).also {
    startActivityForResult(it,101)
}

fun function1(){
      //your function code here
}
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode==101 && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){
           // it will print key value Activity2 : value
           Log.e("key value Activity2", data?.extras.getString("key"))
           function1()
        }
}
```

**Activty2**

```
override fun onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy()
    val returnIntent = Intent()
    returnIntent.putExtra("key", "value")
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)
    finish()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for :D

Comment: I've done! Unluckly someone downvoted your answer so you was at "-1" ... with my upvote you are at "0" now. I'm so sorry :/

Answer (score -1):

yeah, you can send action or some flag, and receive this flag in next activity.
This was one way, other way you can use startActivityForResult, and use same way as above.